# How to use an iterator in Python to grab next line from file, check if it matches regex, and add to an array if it matches?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and have been assigned the task of parsing a text file to search for certain information and add that information to an array.

Here is an example of what I need to do:

1. Read file
2. Check for "*test, test =_"
3. Skip that line
4. While next lines only contains numbers, commas, and space
5. Add numbers from that line to an array named Bnodes

File Contains Following Lines:

```
*test, test=_TestSet312, internal, instance=Test_LM_3Z1-1

11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26
27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37, 240, 241, 242, 243
```

I read the file and passed it in as an object named f so I can iterate over

```
with open(BoundaryFile, 'r') as f:
```

So far my code uses "*test, test = " to identify which line to skip. I skip that current line and I want to add all of the following lines to an array as long as they only contain digits, comma, and a space (this is where I am having trouble).

I am not sure how to check if the next line only contains numbers, comma, and a space.

So far I came up with something like this:

Section of Code I am having trouble on:

```
pattern = re.compile("/\d(, +\d)?/")    
Bnodes = []
while(pattern.match(next(f))):
Bnodes.append(next(f))
```

I know this is probably not the best way to approach this. Are there any better ways that provide an efficient solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question properly. From my understanding, you read the first line of a file and check if it matches a pattern. If it does, then you read all the subsequent lines that match a different pattern of comma separated numbers. This ends on EOF or if the pattern no longer matches. Is that right?

Comment: @SandeepDcunha Correct I want it to match the first pattern, read all subsequent lines that match the next pattern and add them to an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think a regex is the correct way to check it, but your current regex will also match `12, 12, 31adsf` which is not what you want if I understand correctly.

Your regex needs to be more like `/^[\d ,]+$/`. You want to match `\d` `,` and  . Those characters can happen one or more times so we add a `+`. Finally we need to add `^` and `$` to specify that the string starts with that list of characters and after all of the digits, commas and spaces the line terminates. Otherwise it will still match `12, 12, 31adsf` or `asdf12,12,`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
f = open('initfile.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()

Bnodes = []

for l in lines:
    if re.match(r'^[0-9 ,]',l) != None:
        lList = l[:-1].split(", ")
        intList = list(map(int, list(lList)))
        Bnodes.append(intList)

print(Bnodes)
```

Note: `Bnodes` is bot correct style for a variable, CapWords / upper camel case is reserved for classes. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your regex code.

The first is the slashes. Some programming languages that have special syntax for regular expressions use forward slashes `/` to bound regex patterns. Python doesn't have special regex systax. A pattern being passed to `re.compile` (or one of the other functions in the `re` module) is just a normal Python string. That means that you should not include slashes in the pattern (unless you actually want to match slashes in the input text).

Note that you *may* want to use special Python syntax for your pattern strings. Specifically, you may want to use "raw" string literals, which prevents Python from interpreting escape sequences itself, and leaving them intact for the regex engine to interpret. As an example of how Python escapes are problematic for regex, the Python string `'\b'` is equivalent to `'\x08'` (an ASCII backspace character). If you wanted it to be interpreted as part of a regex pattern (where a backslash character followed by a `b` character means a word-break), you'd probably want to write it as `r'\b'` (the `r` making it a "raw string"). You could also escape the backslash (with another backslash), `'\\b'`, but raw strings are often easier to read.

So now we can get to the specific pattern you need to use to match your input. You want to accept lines that contain only comma and space separated numbers. The pattern you're currently using only checks if the first character is a digit, optionally followed by a comma, some spaces, and another digit. It doesn't check the rest of the line, nor does it support numbers that are more than one digit long. To fix it, you should make sure it will check an unlimited lengths and quantities of numbers, and that it checks all the way to the end of the line:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\d+(, *\d+)*$")
```

Your current iteration code will fetch two lines from the file on each cycle, since you're calling `next` twice. That's clearly not what you want. A more natural way to iterate over the file until you find either a line that doesn't match the pattern or the end of the file, would be to use a `for` loop with a `break` statement in it:

```
for line in f:
    if pattern.match(line):
         Bnodes.append(line)
    else:
         break
```